# Mapping from Poincare's disk model to UHP

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-construction, noneuclidean-geometry

I have a question that :

How can I map any point in Poincare's disk model to Upper-half-plane model?
I know the function

$$f(z) =  \frac{z + i}{iz+1}$$

But I want to know the geometric constructive method.
Would you help me?

Comment: By "the geometric constructive method" do you mean compass and straightedge?

Comment: @Rory//  Yes,, you are right. I want the Euclidian contruction.

Comment: Some advice: You have asked six questions and given little positive feedback. This will soon discourage people from answering your questions (it almost discouraged me). You should go back to all six questions, upvote all helpful answers by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of each question, and accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left. That is the standard way to show appreciation on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a little easier to construct the equivalent

$$f(z)=\frac{z+i}{i(z-i)}$$

[image]

Given point $z$ in the complex plane, draw the points $z+i$ and $z-i$ one unit above and below $z$. You could use the obvious parallelograms with $z$, $0$, $i$, and each of those two points. Then rotate the line segment from $0$ to $z-i$ by $90°$ counterclockwise to get point $i(z-i)$.

We now have the numerator and denominator of our fraction. We now use the facts that (1) the modulus of $\frac uv$ is the ratio of the moduli of $u$ and $v$, and (2) the argument (angle) of $\frac uv$ is the difference of the arguments of $u$ and $v$.

To get the correct modulus, draw a vertical line from the intersection (point $A$ in my diagram) of the ray from $0$ to $z-i$ with the unit circle. Mark the intersection of this line with the ray from $0$ to $z+i$ (point $B$ in my diagram). By similar triangles, point $B$ has the desired ratio of moduli.

To get the correct angle, copy the signed angle of $i(z-i)$ to $0$ to the positive real axis (shown in red) to the ray from $0$ to $z+i$. The argument of points on that ray have the desired difference of arguments in our fraction.

The desired $f(z)$ is then the intersection of that last ray with the circle that goes through point $B$ and is centered at the origin. That intersection has both the correct modulus and the correct argument.

The only problem I see with this construction is that point $B$ and thus point $f(z)$ is undefined when $z$ is on the imaginary axis. This is easily handled by rotating point $A$ off the imaginary axis then continuing.

Comment: Thank you kindly answer and good advise. I didn't recognize the upper-arrow and check mark. I will memorize your advice. And one folling question  : In your construct , Are there no posibility that f(z) sink down x-axis?

Comment: Parden me one more question : I have difficult in typing mathmatic equation  in this site. Where I can find  some manual for help?

Comment: @c-301: $f(z)$ is on the real axis if an only if $z$ is on the unit circle with the point $i$ removed. ($f(i)$ is undefined.) That's why the function is from the *interior of the unit circle* to the *open half-plane $\operatorname{Im}(u)>0$*. The exterior of the unit circle is mapped to the lower half-plane. A good tutorial for formatting math at this site is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).